# Remove files with wildcard

Tags: go

I am trying to delete files with a wildcard like shell scripts like:

**`c:\del 123_*`**

My trial as below was failed.

```
os.RemoveAll("/foo/123_*")
os.Remove("/foo/123_*")
```

I guess I need to use some library to use a wildcard.
What is good practice for deleting files with a wildcard?

Comment: Read the directory, select the files wich match the desired pattern and Remove them. No library but some programming.

Comment: Or something with [`filepath.Glob`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob).

Comment: The wildcard `*` is a feature of the shell, not one of the file system. So you have to go through the list of files and test their names against a pattern. The `regexp` package can deal with complicated patterns, however `strings.HasPrefix(str, prefix)` can do the task at hand quite well.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As people mentioned wildcard is a feature of shell (e.g. Windows `cmd.exe`) not OS and usually programming languages don't provide equivalent of `del xyz*`. You should use `Glob` function to find files you want to delete.

```
files, err := filepath.Glob("/foo/123_*")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
for _, f := range files {
    if err := os.Remove(f); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```